# Domain without SPF DKIM and DMARC

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

I am looking for domains that don't have SPF DKIM and DMARC records.

The biggest issue is I can't verify that if a domain is using DKIM,
does anybody konw any domain which doesn't have those 3 authentication records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you can't tell very easily, because you can't find out the DKIM selectors to look up in DNS. You can look for a `_domainkey` policy record that might contain something like `o=~`, though that's a leftover from the older domainkeys spec rather than DKIM. Best case, you'll have an email from the domain that does or does not contain a DKIM signature. A domain is very unlikely to have DMARC if it doesn't have DKIM.

If you're really desperate, and really want just any domain that you can show failing a test, just register a domain yourself and don't make those records for it - a bit like neverssl.com does for SSL.